# "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" while using contract in a separate project

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Lets say I have a solution with 4 projects:

1. Namespace.Contracts - contains IContract interface
2. Namespace.Plugin.A - contains class A - IContract implementation. Class A is exported using MEF
3. Namespace.App - application that imports IContract classes from different locations including Plugin.A's assembly

I receive "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" runtime exception while composing in project 3 - MEF complains that IContract type cannot be found in Namspace.App ... why does it look for it in this namespace and not Namespace.Contracts?
If I move IContract namespace to Namespace.App project it works... what do I miss? How should I compose the parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `ReflectionTypeLoadException` is what you get when your assembly references a type that does not exist. This is not specific to MEF; you'll see the same exception if you load the troublesome assembly and enumerate its types like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("trouble.dll");
assembly.GetTypes();
```

In your case, you have at some point compiled a plugin assembly which references the type `Namespace.App.IContract`. You then copied this assembly to the application bin folder where it could be picked up by MEF.

Later, you moved the `IContract` interface to another `Namespace.Contracts` assembly - but the old plugin assembly is still expecting that type in its previous location. You need to recompile the plugin assembly and redeploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have added all the assemblies to the MEF container before loading? Please display the code that you use to compose.
Should look something like this to load all assemblies in a directory:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@".\"));
```

I'm using this method to load MEF:

```
private bool Load(IEnumerable<string> addinDirectories)
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()));
    foreach (string dir in addinDirectories)
    {
        DirectoryCatalog dc = new DirectoryCatalog(dir);
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(dc);
    }
    this.container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
    batch.AddPart(this);
    batch.AddExportedValue(container);

    this.container.Compose(batch);

    return this.success;
}
```

The input is all the directories where my MEF assemblies are location, incl. the executing directory.

Comment: Failing to add an assembly to the container does not cause the described ReflectionTypeLoadException. That's a different kind of failure.

Comment: Also note that your method will not pick up assemblies in the executables' directory other than the exe itself (unless you have "." in the `addinDirectories`).

Comment: @Wim, that's what I wrote in the last line, the executing directory. And that's the error I normally get, when MEF can't find a required export.